# get ''expected-doctype-but-got-chars " error when i use html5lib of python?

Tags: python, html5lib

This is my code:

```
from html5lib import treebuilders, HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("lxml"))
parser.parse("hello world!")
print parser.errors
```

what cause the error?

But the doc of html5lib use this:

```
import html5lib
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=html5lib.getTreeBuilder("dom"))
minidom_document = parser.parse("<p>Hello World!")
```

Comment: You're elements probably need to be inside tags. Try `parser.parse("<div>hello world!</div>")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I use the after code it success:

```
parser.parse("<!DOCTYPE html>hello world!")
```

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLParser.errors` contains all parse errors from parsing the document; html5lib should handle all parse errors gracefully by default (and yes, the documentation does contain examples that generate parse errors — the aim is to document the API, not show good HTML usage!), and hence unless you are for some reason concerned about parse errors (unless you have a good reason to be, don't be), its value is totally irrelevant.